# Data is displayed strange when parsed with papaparse

Tags: angular, highcharts, papaparse

I am trying to display csv data in highcharts via an input, for this i need papaparse.

My Data looks like this:

```
Tasks,Run,Count
task1,4.96,150
task2,156.166666666667,150
task3,279.369565217391,92
task4,1718,16
task5,2.375,16
```

Therefore, the graph sould display my data like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zrbk8q49

However, when using papaparse and an input, the data gets displayed very strangely:
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-opcho

What is wrong here? How can I display the data correctly with my papaparse/input example?

Answer (score -1):

> the data gets displayed very strangely

What do you mean by that? It looks the same.

**Code:**

```js
var csv = Papa.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML);

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  data: {
    rows: csv.data
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mholt/PapaParse/master/papaparse.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>

<pre id="data">Tasks,Run,Count
task1,4.96,150
task2,156.166666666667,150
task3,279.369565217391,92
task4,1718,16
task5,2.375,16</pre>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tm67p3fc/

Comment: have you tried the codesandbox? it clearly does not look the same. I was asking what my problem there was.

Comment: The problem is that your code is bad and you are not analyzing it to find the issue. It is not a problem with Highcharts or papaparse. I showed you that this works nicely in the posted fiddle. Check this example where I changed a bit your code, it works correctly: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-hkkry.

Comment: I know that my code is bad. That's why i am here. To ask what is wrong with my code.